# Hangman that saves wrong guesses in array and prints them before each guess. also prints gameboard with "_" and correct guesses

Tags: java

so I've been studying Java for about 3 months and I am supposed to do a Hangman code using only arrays, loops, and if statements. the word to be guesses is read from another file and saved as a string. I have to be able to save the wrong guesses in an array. and after each guess print all the wrong guesses so far, as well as the gameboard with underscores for not guessed letters and the correct guesses of course in their place. here is my code so far :

```
for(int l = 0; l<wordlength;l++)
{
    System.out.print("_");
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("WRONG: ");
for(int c = 0; c<numofGuesses;c++)
{  
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("GUESS"+guessN+"/"+numofGuesses+": ");   
    char guess1=in.next().charAt(0);
    char guess = Character.toUpperCase(guess1);
    guessN = guessN+1;
    for (int j = 0; j<wordlength;j++)
    {
        if (guess==guessword.charAt(j))
        {
          System.out.println("Great guess!");
          System.out.print (guessword.charAt(j));
        }
        else 
        {
          System.out.print("_");
          WRONG[u]=guess;
          u++;
        }
    }
```

if you guess A it prints correctly "A___" but then if you guess B after instead of printing "AB__" (the word to guess is ABLE) i get "B__" also the wrong array is not storing and printing all the wrong guesses each time. please help I've been trying for 5 days and that's all I did the entire day today and I couldn't get past this.

Comment: Step 1) Proper indentation

Comment: I suggest you Store the letter to be guessed to a `StringBuilder` variable  and loop it's character to become `_` then also declare and initialized a String variable to be guessed Something like `String toBeGuessed="able"` then `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("____");` <----same letter and length of toBeGuessed String

Answer (score 1):

Because this sounds a lot like a homework assignment, I will give directions for solving this, but not provide a full working solution. Hopefully, seeing how one could<sup>1</sup> go about approaching such a problem is enough of a step in the right direction to be able to solve it yourself.

Let's first think about what we need to do.

1. Read a word that needs to be guessed, say `String toBeGuessed`.
   You did this. ✔
2. Keep track of the characters the player has guessed so far.
3. Keep track of the number of turns a player has gotten.
4. Keep track of if the word has been guessed (player won!).

Say that the number of guesses a player can make is fixed. This can be modeled using a constant:

```
/**
 * Number of guesses a player can take.
 */
public static final int NUM_GUESSES = 10;
```

Now let's think about the main logic of our hangman game. It is good to first think about the structure of your program and only later actually implement it. When thinking of the program structure, we don't bother with specifics of the programming language of your choice yet. In [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode), it would be something like the following, maybe (let's indicate what you already have with ✔).

```
for turn from 1 upto NUM_GUESSES do                   ✔
  show player what they guessed so far
  show the gameboard
  ask player for their new guess                      ✔
  save player's guess and update internal state
  check if the player won, let them know if they did
if player did not win
  let them know
```

Right. So, we need to somehow store the guesses that a player made. Every guess is a character, and we know there will be at most `NUM_GUESS` guesses in total. A good option (and one that is suggested by your exercise) is an array!

```
/**
 * Characters that have been guessed so far.
 */
private char[] guessed;
```

This can be initialized as follows, since we know the maximum number of guesses:

```
this.guessed = new char[NUM_GUESSES];
```

This gives us an array of `NUM_GUESSES` characters that are initialized to 0 ([see here](//stackoverflow.com/q/9909333/962603)). Since users won't guess that character, we can use it to represent guesses that have not been done yet. Alternatively, we can keep track of the current turn of the player in a separate variable. Your choice!

In the following, I will not keep track of the current turn in a separate variable, just to show more of arrays and loops. It might be a fun exercise to change this to using an `int turn` variable!

**show player what they guessed so far**
Alright, this should be fairly straightforward now. We basically need to print the part of the `guessed` array that is not 0. That can be done using a loop, like so for example:

```
System.out.print("You so far guessed: ");
for (int i = 0; i < guessed.length; ++i) {
  if (i > 0) {
    System.out.print(", ");
  }
  if (guessed[i] != 0) {
    System.out.print(guessed[i]);
  } else {
    break; // stop the loop as soon as we run into a 0
  }
}
System.out.println(".");
```

This will print something like `You so far guessed: a, b, c.` when the player guessed those characters. See how we only print the comma when some other character was printed before?

**show the gameboard**
The next point of the program structure is trickier to get right. Let's think a bit about structure again.

```
for each character in toBeGuessed
  if the character has been guessed
    print it
  else
    print an underscore
```

Looping over every character of a word can be done as follows.

```
int length = toBeGuessed.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
  char character = toBeGuessed.charAt(i);
  // do something with character here
}
```

How do you find if a character has been guessed yet? Well, by checking if it is stored in the `guessed` array. This again can be done using a loop. That loop will be very similar to the one we have written above, when showing what the player guessed so far. I think you should be able to figure that one out.

**save player's guess and update internal state**
We move on to the next point of the program structure. Say that we have a `char guess` that the player guessed. We need to store this in our array `guessed`. Where? Well, at the first open spot, that seems a reasonable choice. To find that one, let's use a loop again, and [`break`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) the loop when we have found an open spot.

```
for (int i = 0; i < guessed.length; ++i) {
  if (guessed[i] == 0) {
    guessed[i] = guess;
    break;
  }
}
```

**check if the player won, let them know if they did**
What we need to know in order to see if the player won, is simply if the number of characters they guessed right is equal to the number of characters in `toBeGuessed`. You could modify the loop for showing the gameboard to not print characters, but count correct ones. Then at the end compare to `toBeGuessed.length()` and if they are equal, the player won.

**if player did not win, let them know**
This should be fairly easy, if you got the previous point working.

---

When you did all the above and stitched it together, you should have a working version of hangman. Your very own, something to be proud of!

Some tips and tricks:

- you can implement most of the points described above as separate methods;
- when you do so, you can write one main method that calls the other methods (this will make it easier to read your own code and make changes to it);
- try to put as little code as possible in the `main` method.

Here is a little template that you can start from.

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HangMan
{
  /** Number of guesses a player can take. */
  public static final int NUM_GUESSES = 10;

  /** Word to be guessed in a game of hangman. */
  private String toGuess;
  /** Letters that have been guessed so far. */
  private char[] guessed;

  /**
   * Construct a new game of hangman, ready to be played.
   */
  public HangMan(String toGuess)
  {
    this.toGuess = toGuess;
    this.guessed = new char[NUM_GUESSES];
  }

  // your other methods go here

  /**
   * Read guesses from given input and print results to given output.
   * Continues until guesses have run out, or word was guessed.
   */
  public void play(Scanner in, PrintStream out)
  {
    for (int round = 0; round < NUM_GUESSES; ++round) {
      showGuessedSoFar(out);
      showGameBoard(out);
      char guess = askGuess(in, out);
      saveGuess(guess);
      if (hasPlayerWon()) {
        out.println("You won!");
        return;
      }
    }
    // at this point, player ran out of guesses and hence lost
    out.println("You lost...");
  }

  /**
   * The bit that runs our hangman game.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // read word to guess from arguments, with a default value
    // you would probably insert your "read word from file" code here
    HangMan game = new HangMan(args.length >= 1 ? args[0] : "ABLE");
    // play a game, using system input and output
    game.play(new Scanner(System.in), System.out);
  }
}
```

Good luck!

**TL;DR.** Trying to teach one how to think about a problem and how to write code that executes the solution one thought of. Features some example code with arrays and loops.

<sub><sup>1</sup> This is only one possible solution, there are always many ways to solve a given problem.</sub>